# Counting unique rows in spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do you run the COUNTUNIQUE function on several columns?

Running COUNTUNIQUE(A1:C3) gives me 8, because there are 8 unique values, I want it to return 3 because I have 3 unique rows.

```
| A  | B  |  c  |
-----------------
| a  | 1  |     |
| b  | 2  | foo |
| b  | 2  | foo |
| c  | 3  | bar |
```

P.S. I use Google spreadsheets, but I guess it's the same in Excel and LibreOffice Calc

Comment: Did you find the answer of @joseph4tw useful? I know I did. Perhaps you can flag it as such and let other people benefit from your Q&A!

Comment: See mquan86 for a easier to understand solution. BillN also suggested this but didn't explicitly write out a formula for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheets:

```
=count(unique(A2:C5))
```

Comment: This only works by accident. See my answer for a more robust solution.

This appears to work for the particular example provided, but not for the right reasons. COUNT() returns the number of *numeric* values in a range. It returns 3 in this case because there are 3 numeric values.

Try replacing the 3 in the example data with an 'A' and you will see what I mean. This formula will return a 2, which is not the number of unique rows.

Comment: @AminMesbah touché. Nice answer. Upvoted

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way I can think of is to concatenate the three vaules into column D and do the CountUnique on Column D

Answer (score 3):

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A&B1:B&C1:C))
```

Comment: That was also my solution. I like to keep things as easy to read as possible. Good Job.

Answer (score 2):

After spending several hours on this problem, I've finally found a solution:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(UNIQUE(A1:C4), "select count(Col1) label count(Col1) ''"))`

UNIQUE(A1:C4) returns the unique rows in the range:

- `a, 1,`
- `b, 2, foo`
- `c, 3, bar`

Then QUERY() treats those rows as a new range and counts how many items there are in the first column, which ends up being the number of unique rows: 3. The label at the end of the query just gets rid of the header, 'Count' that it would normally return.

There should really be a much simpler way to do this, but this method has proven to be adequate for my purposes, and adaptable to several similar problems.